# I don't understand why $rootScope works but not $scope in this case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app, that places `ng-app` within the `<html>` tag instead of the body, so that the angular scope would cover the `<title>`. However, from within the angular controller, the `$scope` variable is not able to output anything within the `<title>` but `$rootScope` is. I don't understand why this is the case. As far as I know, `$scope` is local to the controller and `$rootScope` is global. However, in this case, I ensured that the `ng-app` was placed in the `<html>` tag so that `<title>` would be covered. As far the `ng-controller` is concerned, I am not really specifying it anywhere within my html page.

```
<html ng-app="my-app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{scopeVar}}</title>
```

Any hints?

Comment: The controller's scope is wherever you define `ng-controller` (or which view it is attached to in the case of a router, etc.). If you don't explicitly attach it to any element, then, no, the controller's scope won't cover anything.

Comment: I am using `ui-router`, hence not explicitly mentioning `ng-controller` within my html file. But does that mean my controller will be automatically bound to `ui-view`?

Comment: Yes, controllers are specific to their views as declared in the ui-router configuration.

Comment: @deceze Cool. Would you mind putting that up as an answer? I would like to officially "select" it.

Comment: Update your question with information about ui-router, otherwise it's not much use for future visitors.

Comment: Sorry? But that's all my question entails... and you've answered me enough for me understand the problem.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow aren't only for yourself. They serve as a reference for future visitors with the same problem. It would help those people probably if you included the exact circumstances of how your problem came about, so they can search for and find the right keywords.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have bothered you enough. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @deceeze, the reason why $rootScope worked but $scope didn't was simply because when working with `ui-router`, the controller is tied to the `ui-view`. Hence, anything outside of that will not be covered by `$scope`. But `$rootScope` on the other hand is global, and that covers anything within `ng-app`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="controller_name">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{scopeVar}}</title>
</head>
</html>
```

put your controller in `<html>` it will work with scope too.Because $scope is available in its controller and $rootScope is global to complete app.

Answer (score 0):

**Grateful**, when you add "ng-app" tag Angular gives you the $rootScope. When you create a controller Angular gives you a $scope.

Prefer to create small controllers and put then where you want. When you create small controllers, you can use $scope for each one. Below i created two controllers, one to handler de header and other to handle my body. The "**scopeVar**" variable will be available in *controller1*.

```
<html ng-app="my-app">
<head ng-controller="controller1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{scopeVar}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="controller2">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT, if you want to communicate from your controller to $rootScope, don't use $rootScope.somevariable = 'foo'. Use $broadcast and $emmit services to do that. Ex.:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event name', 'foo');
```

In your RUN configuration for the app you can listen that:

```
$rootScope.$on('event name', function(param1){
   // param1 will be 'foo'
   // do something
});
```